# Post to two different URLs with Ajax/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

i am having an customer / newsletter opt-in form which is quite simple. When a customers subscribes, i am posting the data via Ajax to the "mail.php" form which then sends out an E-Mail to the shop that has been selected and informs them. On the other hand, the action of the subscribe form is an external URL which gets the POST parameters and parses them into an external subscriber system.

My problem here is i can get it to work to send the e-mail, but after the Ajax action has completed posting on the mail.php i want the script to continue posting it to the external URL. Code looks like this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#subscribeform" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pFirstName = $("#firstname").val();
        var pLastName = $("#name").val();
        var pSalutation = $("#salutation").val();
        var peMail = $("#email").val();
        var pDOB = $("#dob").val();
        var pMailTo = $("#shop").val();

        var data = {
            firstname: pFirstName,
            name: pLastName,
            salutation: pSalutation,
            email: peMail,
            dob: pDOB,
            mailto: pMailTo
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: data,
    success: function(){
        $('#subscribeform').attr('action', "http:///theexternalURL").submit();
    }
    });
    });
});
</script>

<form id="subscribeform" action="http://theexternalURL" method="post">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
```

etc....

I think the main problem is that i am doing this on the onsubmit form with jQuery and even if i try to replace the URL in the success function, the script keeps on getting called and runs in a loop instead of continuing to post to the external URL.

Do you have any directions or ideas what i can change?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `submit()` second time use `$.ajax()` again like,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "theexternalURL",
        data: data, // same date to another url
        success: function(){
           // your final response here
        }
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, i didnt think of that. Originally, when posting the form to the external URL i get a response like if the data is incorrect, it heads me to an error page, if correct to a success page. Is there a way to handle the response?

Comment: I think the server should respond a valid error message in place of a error page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to send the form by adding another $.ajax in your success callback, also the CORS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#subscribeform" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pFirstName = $("#firstname").val();
        var pLastName = $("#name").val();
        var pSalutation = $("#salutation").val();
        var peMail = $("#email").val();
        var pDOB = $("#dob").val();
        var pMailTo = $("#shop").val();

        var data = {
            firstname: pFirstName,
            name: pLastName,
            salutation: pSalutation,
            email: peMail,
            dob: pDOB,
            mailto: pMailTo
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true, // maybe you will need to add this
        url: "http:///theexternalURL/ACTION",
        data: data,

    success: function(){
       // $('#subscribeform').attr('action', "http:///theexternalURL").submit();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(){
                 // SHOW SUCCESS MESSAGE FOR ACTION 2
                }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the ideas and replys.

Ultimatey i used the one() function to make it only triggers once then jump to default action in the success event :

```
$( "#subscribeform" ).one( "submit", function(event) {
```

Thanks !:)